# Client side socket isn't creating (ConnectException)

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have two machines with hostname `q2` and `w18` and I have a two simple program to send some message between these machines using socket. I have one `file.cfg` which contains the `ip` needs to be used by both `Client.java` and `Server.java`.

**Client**

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String... C) {
        try {

            String filePath = "file.cfg";
            String ip = "";

            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
            ip = new String(bytes);
            ip = ip.trim();

            System.out.println("cfg file contains " + ip);

            Socket so = new Socket(ip, 3112);
            System.out.println("socket Connected. " + so.toString());

            so.setSoTimeout(30000);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            String filePath = "file.cfg";
            String ip = "";

            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
            ip = new String(bytes);
            ip = ip.trim();

            System.out.println("cfg file contains" + ip);

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3112, 50, InetAddress.getByName(ip));
            System.out.println("Server Socket is created. " + serverSocket.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Accept...");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted...");


            OutputStreamWriter localOut = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            localOut.write("Hi,");
            localOut.write("Hello");
            localOut.write("\n");
            localOut.flush();
            localOut.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

**file.cfg**

```
10.90.50.101
# this ip will be similar in both machines
# for ref, 
# 10.90.50.101 -> q2 and 
# 10.90.50.102 -> w18
```

**Success Scenarios**

1. I ran both `Client` and `Server` in `w18`, which works fine
2. I ran both `Client` and `Server` in `q2` which works fine
3. I ran `Client` in `q2` and Server in `w18` which works fine

**Failure Scenario**

1. When I ran `Server` in `q2` and `Client` in `w18`. `Client` Socket isn't creating at all. Client throwing below error after some time while creating a socket.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at Client.main(Client.java:21)
```

**Question**

I've seen some `ConnectException` SO's QA's, But here I'm able to achieve the point 3 in **Success Scenarios** but not able to do the same thing vice versa which is `point 1` of **Failure Scenario**.

Comment: maybe firewall issue at q2 (most of firewall allow outgoing connection) so try to debug the network connection and firewall

Comment: @justsomeone How exactly achieve that, I tried so far `systemctl stop firewalld`. Still same

Comment: @user16320675 `cfg file contains 10.90.50.101` and a stacktrace that I posted in the question

Comment: I used `cfg` file just to pick the ip, Instead of hardcoding in the program. In both machines, I use the `same ip` for `Client` and `Server` program from that file.

Comment: @ShashankGb you need to search for that based on your os which i see that you use the firewall of  linux

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, I know. I too tried every other perspective from coding point. And anywhere I didn't mention I need a solution from code. EOD, I have to achieve sending message from one m/c to another as I mentioned in post. Thanks :)

Comment: @justsomeone I am using RHEL6

Comment: sorry but i do not know a lot about rhel6 so better check how to check for firewall log to make sure if it block the port or not

Answer (score 1):

in server.java  try replacing below code

```
 serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3112, 50, InetAddress.getByName(ip));
```

with

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3112, 50, "localhost");
```

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3112, 50, "127.0.0.1");
```

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3112, 50, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Ya. is it working now?

Comment: oh.. I thought you are the author.